# Is there a way to avoid overloading a method with Func<T, ...> argument for each Func parameter count

Tags: c#, delegates, generic-programming

I know the question sounds a bit wierd. Sorry for that, having difficulties trying to get where i want to and even explain it. To make it simple, i have a method with `Func<T>` argument. But i do not always pass a parameterless *Action* to that method, i need **varying** numbers of parameters and i'm trying to find a way to avoid *overloading* my method everytime number of parameters needed is increased

Here is my *generic* class, I need to *overload* `GetInstance` method:

```
public class MethodResult<T>
{
    public T Result { get; set; }
    public bool IsResulted { get; set; }
    public Exception Error { get; set; }

    private MethodResult() { }

    public static MethodResult<T> GetInstance<T>(Func<T> method)
    {
        MethodResult<T> obj = new MethodResult<T>();

        try
        {
            obj.Result = method();
            obj.IsResulted = true;
            obj.Error = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj.Result = default(T);
            obj.IsResulted = false;
            obj.Error = ex;
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public static MethodResult<T> GetInstance<T, T1>(Func<T1, T> method, T1 param1)
    {
        MethodResult<T> obj = new MethodResult<T>();

        try
        {
            obj.Result = method(param1);
            obj.IsResulted = true;
            obj.Error = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj.Result = default(T);
            obj.IsResulted = false;
            obj.Error = ex;
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

And here is sample showing how i want to make use of it:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{            
        var x = MethodResult<int>.GetInstance(IntResult, 5);
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}, IsResulted: {1}, ErrorMessage: {2}", x.Result, x.IsResulted, (x.Error == null ? "null" : x.Error.Message));

        var y = MethodResult<string>.GetInstance(SayHello);
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}, IsResulted: {1}, ErrorMessage: {2}", y.Result, y.IsResulted, (y.Error == null ? "null" : y.Error.Message));

        Console.Read();
}

public static int IntResult(int x) { return x + 1; }
public static int IntResult(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
public static string SayHello() { return "Hello world!"; }
```

In order to be able to use `IntResult(int x, int y)` i have to *overload* `GetInstance` method with signiture:

`public static MethodResult<T> GetInstance<T, T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2, T> method, T1 param1, T2 param2)`

It's obvious that this will become very time consuming as it's already been annoying. Is there a way to avoid that much *overloading* ?

Comment: this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096519/overloading-a-method-with-parameter-funct

Comment: Best way I can think of is to use lambdas: `MethodResult<int>.GetInstance(() => IntResult(5));`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair +1 simple as that. No complexity, no dozens of overloadings

Comment: Thank you all, i still find lambda expressions kind of confusing

Comment: @KevinNacios i don't think it's quite similar. Of course i know "Jon Skeet is always right", but his solution chains overloads instead of removing them and using only single definition of a method, which proves true since the problematic is not about getting rid of overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the function to call and the parameters along with it, you can pass a *parameterless anonymous* `delegate` calling the method you want to point to with parameters you want. Just remove any overloads of *GetInstance* just keep:

```
public static MethodResult<T> GetInstance(Func<T> method)
{
    MethodResult<T> obj = new MethodResult<T>();

    try
    {
        obj.Result = method();
        obj.IsResulted = true;
        obj.Error = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj.Result = default(T);
        obj.IsResulted = false;
        obj.Error = ex;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

And then call it as following:

```
int n = 1;
var x = MethodResult<string>.GetInstance(() => SayHello());
var y = MethodResult<string>.GetInstance(() => IntResult(2));
var z = MethodResult<int>.GetInstance(() => IntResult(n, 9));
```